# Simplifying the expression $\frac{ke^{ix}-ke^{ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{ix}}$

Tags: arithmetic, infinity

Say I have ended up with the expression:  $\dfrac{ke^{ix}-ke^{ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{ix}}$.

Let's rewrite it where $A = k$ and $B = e^{ix}$: $\dfrac{AB-AB}{B-B} = \dfrac{(1-1)AB}{(1-1)B}$.

Again let's rewrite it where $C = (1-1)$: $\dfrac{(1-1)AB}{(1-1)B} = \dfrac{CAB}{CB} = A$.

It seems contrived and wrong; I'm trying to get rid of the infinity, but the equation I am trying to derive from equation is probably just wrong.

EDIT:

I got here by trying to solve a differential equation for a piece-wise function $V(x)$, where:
$$V(x) = \begin{cases}
x \lt 0 & 0 \\
0 \leq x \leq L & V_0 \\
x \gt L & 0
\end{cases}
$$

The differential equation is the Time Independent Schrödinger Equation

$\psi( x ) = \frac{-\hbar^2\mathrm{d}^2\psi(x)}{2m\mathrm{d}x^2} + V(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x) \rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}^2\psi(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^2} - \frac{2m(E-V(x))}{\hbar^2}\psi(x) = 0.$

To make things easier: $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2\psi(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^2} - k^2\psi(x) = 0$ where: $k^2 = \dfrac{2m(E-V(x))}{\hbar^2}.$

So when $L < x < 0$ in regions 0 and 2 $k_2^2 = k_0^2 = \dfrac{2m(E-0)}{\hbar^2} = \dfrac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$, and $k_1 = \frac{2m(E-V_0)}{\hbar^2}.$

For this scenario we assume $V_0 < E$ (physical assumption).

We end up with 3 equations

$
\psi_0(x) = Ae^{ik_0x} + Be^{-ik_0x},$
$\psi_1(x) = Ce^{ik_1x} + De^{-ik_1x},$
$\psi_2(x) = Fe^{ik_2x} + Ge^{-ik_2x}.$

Also, due to our physical constraints (no back propagation) $G = 0$, thus:
$\psi_2(x) = Fe^{ik_2x}$.

We also know: $\psi_2(L) = Fe^{ik_2L} = \psi_1(L) = Ce^{ik_1L} + De^{-ik_1L}
$

and: $
psi_0(0) = psi_1(0) = A + B = C + D.$

As the function $\psi(x)$ must be continuous (and exists in a Hilbert Space)

I put everything into an automatic solver to solve for the system, it results in:

$$
A = \frac{F\left(k_{0} \left(k_{1} + i k_{2} + \left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right) e^{2 L k_{1}}\right) + i k_{1} \left(k_{1} + i k_{2} + \left(- k_{1} + i k_{2}\right) e^{2 L k_{1}}\right)\right) e^{- L \left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right)}}{4 k_{0} k_{1}}
$$
$$
B = \frac{F \left(k_{0} \left(k_{1} + i k_{2} + \left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right) e^{2 L k_{1}}\right) + i k_{1} \left(- k_{1} - i k_{2} + \left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right) e^{2 L k_{1}}\right)\right) e^{- L \left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right)}}{4 k_{0} k_{1}}
$$
$$
C = \frac{F\left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right) e^{L \left(k_{1} + i k_{2}\right)}}{2 k_{1}}
$$
$$
D \frac{F\left(k_{1} + i k_{2}\right) e^{- L \left(k_{1} - i k_{2}\right)}}{2 k_{1}}
$$

I attempted to normalize `F`, but this is wrong because its a piecewise function and not equal too the whole probability distribution:

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{L} F \overline{F}\, dx = 1
$$

That's how I got:

$$
\frac{i G e^{i L k_{2}} \overline{G}}{- k_{2} e^{i L \overline{k_{2}}} + e^{i L \overline{k_{2}}} \overline{k_{2}}} - \frac{i G \overline{G}}{- k_{2} + \overline{k_{2}}} = 1
$$

$$
\left|{G}\right| = \sqrt{- \frac{i \left(- k_{2} + \overline{k_{2}}\right) e^{i L \overline{k_{2}}}}{e^{i L k_{2}} - e^{i L \overline{k_{2}}}}}
$$

But its wrong, thats how I got here

Comment: If you end up with that first expression, you've done something wrong. You cannot divide by zero.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I am pretty sure I have. Its also what I get from dividing the imaginary and real parts of a number.

Comment: In that case, it would help if you include the steps that got you to this point. As it stands the expressions you're trying to evaluate don't really make sense, but if this came from, say, taking a limit, then at some earlier point there might be a rigorous treatment to give you a sensible result.

Comment: Its a bit lengthy but I can try @ElliotYu

Comment: @ElliotYu Added it